# Ubuntu freezing resulting in grub error

Tags: 16.04, grub2, freeze, inspiron

Hi I currently have a dell inspiron 15 5000 and I keep encountering this issue on Ubuntu 16.04 Lts. I start the computer and it works for a few minutes afterwards it becomes unresponsive, no matter which program I am currently running, and there is no way to get it working so I have to do a hard reset but once I do, it will restart but takes me to the grub menu and trying to find the boot partition fails evrytime so I end up reinstalling the whole os I have done this 7 times, no joke, and I am not even able to find information on the issue I don't know what to do any information would be appreciated

Comment: I would start by checking that HDD's health.

Comment: I thought that it could be the hard drive but that does not seems to be case, I did a factory reset and reinstalled windows 10 which is the OS that came with and with windows the issue does not happen. any other idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally after almost a week of research, I found an explanation to what was happening with my computer, after being able to use the computer for about 3 minutes before freezing, by using the log viewer, I was able to find the message: amd-vi completion-wait loop timed out, turns out that the issue was with the graphics driver seems to be specific to amd open drivers and iommu which can corrupt the EXT4 partition and because of it I was being sent over the grub recovery menu after doing a hard reset, in order to solve the issue is required to modify GRUB menu, to do this you have to be fast before the computer freezes you need to open a terminal and use any text editor to modify GRUB in my case I used nano

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Once the file is open, we need to modify the following line from

```
GRUB_LINUX_CMD_LINE=""
```

to

```
GRUB_LINUX_CMD_LINE="iommu=soft"
```

once that is taken care of we simply save. if using nano would be Ctrl+O to save and to exit Ctrl+X.

Then we have to update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally reboot and after rebooting the problem should be resolved. Seems to be a common issue on Dell Inspiron and HP laptops with AMD APU's ,and AMD graphics cards. I hope this information is useful to others and as a side note depending on the version of linux you may have the GRUB option may also appear as follows. Keep in mind the solution is the same just add iommu=soft

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
```

Comment: Excellent find! I've herad about this issue years ago but thought it was confined to one or a couple of generations of AMD chipsets.